# regenerating thumbnails using paperclip gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, paperclip

I have a simple rails app and i use paperclip gem for my image processing. after uploading an image with a style like `(:thumb => "30x30#")` and i later want to add a new style like `(:large => "300x300>")`. the problem i am having is that, if i add the new style i would have a broken image link when rendering the image unless i upload a new image or update the old one. is it possible to regenerate the styles of the previously uploaded images? if so i would like to know how or do i have to re-upload the images again to have the new styles.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

went trough the paperclip documentation and found this.

```
rake paperclip:refresh:missing_styles
```

and it worked